Predicting rankings from rankings
I'm doing some modeling of athletic competitions. I want to know how well I can predict the ranked outcome of one competition from a previous competition, where all the competitors are the same. So, the predictor variable is the ranking (1 to N) of the first competition and the outcome variable is another ranking (1 to N).
What kind of model can I use for this process? The options for ranked data are a little confusing and complicated.

You're right that rank data models can be a little weird. Honestly, I'd start by just doing a simple linear regression. Sure, technically you have rank data at integers, but treating it as continous is probably going to give you 90% of the value. Here's an example of an academic study that allows this assumption: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/csranks/vignettes/Rank-Rank-Reg.html

When you say "a previous competition", what do you mean? A single ranking from a previous one-off competition involving all competitors? Are there multiple ranked competition outcomes involving all competitors? Is there win-loss information from one-on-ones between pairs of competitors? This question requires a little more background to give a decent answer

There is a competition with tens of competitors. Then, later, there is another competition with the same competitors. I want to predict the second competitions rankings from the first.

If you have a single ranking of tens of competitors and no other data, then there are no models you can fit or predictions you can make other than the results of the one previous ranking.

there are many instances of the before-after rankings but thanks for the widsom

Do you have only one earlier competition or many? Some other data, like actual finnish times?

I'm just looking at pairs of competitions. One competition. Then another one with the same people.
